# numpy selecting multiple columns excluding certain ones - concise way

Tags: python, numpy

I have a short question about indexing in numpy. I'm trying to select subset of columns of a 2D array. For example, if I wanted columns other than 3, 6 and 9, then I would plug in a list of indicies excluding those positions:

```
x = np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)
x[:, [i for i in range(len(x[0])) if i not in [3, 6, 9]]]
```

```
[[ 0  1  2  4  5  7  8]
 [10 11 12 14 15 17 18]]
```

The method works but I was wondering if there's more concise way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with [numpy.delete()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)
np.delete(x, [3,6,9], axis=1)


[[ 0  1  2  4  5  7  8]
 [10 11 12 14 15 17 18]]
```